# Override Context.PostAsync in the bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework, telegram-bot

I noticed that with the Bot Framework and Telegram channel, the smilies like :) aren't transform to an emoji.

Nevertheless, it very simple, we just need to change :) to :smile: and a nice emoji will appear.

The optimal solution would be to override the `context.PostAsync()` function, to perform those kind of string replacement, and then continue.

Can we override this method, without recompiling the all framework ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that what you are looking is to change the message that the bot sends to the user.

Of course, the basic option is to just add the logic to check for the channel into your bot dialog and that's it. However, I suspect you want to reutilize that logic on other dialogs, which could also mean just a static method somewhere that allows you to do:

```
context.PostAsync(Utils.TransformMessage(message));
```

Now, if you really want to go with the cleanest approach, I think that should implement your own `IMessageActivityMapper` and register that into the Autofac container, so the `MapToChannelData_BotToUser` implementation ends up calling it (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/BotToUser.cs#L259-L283)).

There are a few implementations of the `IMessageActivityMapper` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/BotToUser.cs#L213-L243) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/BotToUser.cs#L247:L257) you can take a look at; though the interface is really simple and the whole idea is that you receives the `IMessageActivity`, update any of the existing properties (in your case it will be the Text property) and return the updated `IMessageActivity` so it can be posted to the user.

Once you have your implementation ready, you can register it in Autofac doing the following in your `Global.asax.cs`.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        // http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#quick-start
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register your mapper 
        builder
        .RegisterType<MyActivityMapper>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();

        // Get your HttpConfiguration.
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```